# Firestore whereEqualTo object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've been searching the docs for hours and I still can't see an example where they show a use case like this.

I have the following code below but it returns nothing.

```
val obj = mapOf(
    "type" to "Admin"
)

Firebase.firestore
    .collection("Caves")
    .whereEqualTo("author", obj)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Debug.log("success: %s", it.documents.size) // it.size is also 0 where it should be 3
    }
```

The sample data structure looks like the following:

```
"Caves"
[
    {
        author: {
            type: "Admin",
            id: 123,
            displayName: "Test"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

In C#, this would be as simple as: `caves.Where(e => e.Author.Type == Type.Admin)`

Is there a way to use `whereEqualTo()` against an object?

Did I structure my data wrong?

---

**Edit:**

Screenshot of Firestore data:
[image]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your firestore structure? I am asking this as I am confused by your representation above since you added it in this structure: `[{{}}]`, this would mean that inside the `Caves` collection the author object that you want to get is an object inside another object inside an array, that is not correct is it? If possible please share the screenshot as it would make it simpler to understand.

Comment: @RafaelLemos yes. I put an object within a collection. Am I doing it wrong? Should it be limited to key/value pairs only? I have added the screenshot btw.

Comment: I thought it exists in an array. Doug's answer is right ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter documents based on a nested property of a map field, you can use dot notation to specify that:

```
Firebase.firestore
    .collection("Caves")
    .whereEqualTo("author.type", "Admin")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        Debug.log("success: %s", it.documents.size) // it.size is also 0 where it should be 3
    }
```

Note the field "author.type".  The only mention of dot notation is in the [documentation for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), but it works for queries as well.

Comment: This is working great, thank you! I actually didn't look on `update`-related queries, welp.